Managing Gorilla WebSocket Connections in a Real-Time Application
I'm currently working on a real-time application that utilizes Gorilla WebSocket in conjunction with Next.js. One of the challenges I'm facing is that when a user refreshes the page, a new WebSocket connection is established. This causes the user to lose control of their session or data, especially in multiplayer games where continuity is crucial.
Is there a recommended approach or best practice to handle WebSocket connections in a way that maintains session integrity even if the user refreshes the page? Ideally, I'd like to ensure that the user retains their session state and doesn't lose their place or control upon refreshing.
I am currently working on trying to use cookies to store the client id, but I'm not sure how to reconnect the user to the same websocket connection given a client id.
Update:
I have this code block. Is this the correct way to add a cookie in Golang?
 expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
    cookie := http.Cookie{
        Name:     "client_uuid",
        Value:    c.uuid,
        Expires:  expiration,
        Secure:   false,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }

    http.SetCookie(c.w, &cookie)

This http.SetCookie(c.w, &cookie) line causes a pointer nil error by the way.

Store session state separately from the connection and give the state a unique identifier.
Before upgrading form HTTP to WS in your handler, check for a session ID cookie.  If there is a valid session ID cookie in the request, then associate the connection with that session.  Otherwise, start a new session and set a Set-Cookie header in the arguments to Upgrade.

Hi, thanks for your response; I've added a code block to the original post; is it correct?
